# ResolveInfo items from queryIntentActivityOptions have priority always 0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, share

I'm implementing custom share feature for `ACTION_SEND` intent. I want to exclude my own app from sharing list. To achieve this I'm getting all suitable activities using `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivityOptions(...)` and then checking the package.

The problem is that `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivityOptions(...)` returns me a list of `ResolveInfo` objects where `priority` is always `0` and apps are ordered wrong - not like in the default share dialog. Thus apps don't have a proper order in a list and it's not convenient for user.
Here is a code which does sharing:

```
 public void shareExcludingApp(String packageNameToExclude, Uri imagePath) {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createShareIntent(imagePath), 0);

    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            Intent targetedShare = createShareIntent(imagePath);

            if (!info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageNameToExclude)) {
                targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            }
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), mContext.getString(R.string.choose_an_app));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        mContext.startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }

}

private Intent createShareIntent(Uri uri) {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return share;
}
```

Am I configuring the intent wrong? Do I need to supply more data somewhere?
Thanks

---

### Update:

Thanks to @CommonsWare I realized that I shouldn't use `priority` to order the list myself, instead the list should be sorted already (queryIntentActivities):

> Returns a List of ResolveInfo objects containing one entry for each matching activity, ordered from best to worst.

But it's not sorted properly in my case and I'm getting activities mixed up. Can you please help me?

Comment: AFAIK, `priority` is driven by `android:priority` attributes on `<intent-filter>` elements, and as such aren't going to be used for ordering things in dialogs. You could sort your `targetedShareIntents` (e.g., `Collections.sort()`) by some criteria, such as name.

Comment: right thank you. My problem now is why activity list isn't sorted properly. Docs say: 
`Returns a List of ResolveInfo objects containing one entry for each matching activity, ordered from best to worst.`